# VIM equivalent of IntelliJ's expand/shrink selection?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim

How would one achieve the same result.  I believe the keybinding for macOS Intellij is op+up/down and on windows it is alt+w/d.

Essentially the function highlights the current word, then, with successive presses, expands out to the full string/line/area in-between parenthesis/further out to the next set of parenthesis.  Very useful for developing in LISP.

The closest I've gotten is this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19028

Comment: I've found that va{ and vi{ work quite nicely. Although now I would have to use different keybindings like shift+v for selecting a line instead of successively using the same keybinding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this plug in: https://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region

It expands selections based on Vim’s text objects.

Comment: I'm a little late back to this but this is sick! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well this may seem comfortable but does not correspondent with the internal logic of vim itself.

See, in vim everything you enter is like a sentence. `va{` for example: there is a verb `v` -> visually select and an object (or movement) `{` -> paragraph. In this case there is also a modifier `a` around. You can exchange stuff in this sentence and it will still work `vaw`, `dil`, `cB` and so on. The power of vim is greatly based on that concept.

Of course you can write a function that does `vaw` first, then `S-v` and lastly `va{` but that will only work with visual selection. It will not work with `c` or `d` or anything. So I will recommend to get used to use different keys for different actions.

The visual selection is mostly not needed anyway. Change a paragraph? directly use `ca}` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that VI/VA + WOBO (as many times as you need to expand) works similarly. Not as fast but its the same concept and you can even expand/shrink asymmetrically based on your WO's and BO's (Or OW's and OB's depending on how you look at it)